# Cannot access opened port in AWS from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, aws-security-group

I have developed an `Angular 4` app inside my `AWS` `instance`. `instance` base image is `windows`. my **Angular** app runs on `port 7000` inside the `AWS instance`. then I opened the `port 7000` from **security group** using `AWS Console` and with the **firewall** using `AWS instance`. but I cannot `access` or see it from `outside` as `publicly`. it is running properly inside the instance on **port 7000**. What did I do wrong, or are there many more steps to achieve this. hope your help with this,

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful if you posted most details. What does your security group look like? Are you also using a Load Blanceer?

Try setting your inbound to 0.0.0.0/0 (not recommended) or select "My IP" and try to access your instance via IP port ip-address:7000.

Cheers!

Comment: This should have been added as comment.